# Este programa está dando Runtime Error no uri, gostaria de saber onde estou errando

Tags: c, runtime

```
 #include <stdio.h>  
 #include <stdlib.h>  
 #include <math.h>  
 #include <string.h>  

 int main(){
     short int numCasos, i = 1, j = 1, soma = 0;
     long long int num;

     scanf("%hd", &numCasos);

     while(i <= numCasos){
         scanf("%lld", &num);

         while(j <= num){
             if(num % j == 0) soma++;

             j++;
         }

         if(soma == 2) printf("%lld eh primo\n", num);
         else printf("%lld nao eh primo\n", num);

         soma = 0;
         j = 1;
         i++;
     }

     return 0;
    }
```

Descrição do problema:

Na matemática, um Número Primo é aquele que pode ser dividido somente por 1 (um) e por ele mesmo. Por exemplo, o número 7 é primo, pois pode ser dividido apenas pelo número 1 e pelo número 7.
Entrada

A entrada contém vários casos de teste. A primeira linha da entrada contém um inteiro N (1 ≤ N ≤ 100), indicando o número de casos de teste da entrada. Cada uma das N linhas seguintes contém um valor inteiro X (1 < X ≤ 107), que pode ser ou não, um número primo.
Saída

Para cada caso de teste de entrada, imprima a mensagem “X eh primo” ou “X nao eh primo”, de acordo com a especificação fornecida.

Comment: Onde a variável "num" está sendo incrementada? Será que ele não se perdeu no segundo "while"?

Comment: @RodrigoTognim: a variável "num" é atribuída um valor com o "scanf".

Comment: long long é uma novidade do C99. Talvez o compilador do uri seja um compilador de C89 e dê erro de compilação (não é erro de runtime).

Comment: Esse era o problema, o long long, o Uri não deve aceitar, usei unsigned long e deu certo! Obrigado pessoal!